# Why are some aggregates treated differently in the RHS of a rule in the model clause?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

With my limited understanding of the model clause, I'd expected the following three queries to return the same results because there are no nulls in the data, and the functions are equivalent:

```
select *
from (select level k, 100 v from dual connect by level<=2)
model return updated rows
dimension by (k)
measures (v, 0 shr)
rules ( shr[any] = v[cv()]/sum(v)[any] );  --plain sum
/*
         K          V        SHR
---------- ---------- ----------
         1        100        0.5 
         2        100        0.5 
*/
select *
from (select level k, 100 v from dual connect by level<=2)
model return updated rows
dimension by (k)
measures (v, 0 shr)
rules ( shr[any] = v[cv()]/nullif(sum(v)[any],0) ); --with nullif
/*
         K          V        SHR
---------- ---------- ----------
         1        100       0.25   <------\___ why?
         2        100       0.25   <------/
*/
select *
from (select level k, 100 v from dual connect by level<=2)
model return updated rows
dimension by (k)
measures (v, 0 shr)
rules ( shr[any] = v[cv()]/decode(sum(v)[any],0,null,sum(v)[any]) );  -- with decode
/*
         K          V        SHR
---------- ---------- ----------
         1        100        0.5 
         2        100        0.5 
*/
```

What am I missing about the processing of rules that explains this behaviour?

<sub>*SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/15991)*</sub>

Comment: Bonkers. Will investigate!

Comment: Have you reported the bug or looked on Metalink?

Comment: No, I wasn't sure I wasn't missing something obvious at first. Have you got 12c to test?

Comment: same behaviour in 12c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the [Oracle Database SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions116.htm#i1001340) one can read

> NULLIF(expr1, expr2)
>   ...
>   The NULLIF function is logically equivalent to the following CASE expression:
>       CASE WHEN expr1 = expr2 THEN NULL ELSE expr1 END

but Oracle 11.2.0.3 on Linux gives the following

```
SQL>select *
  2  from (select level k, 100 v from dual connect by level<=2)
  3  model return updated rows
  4  dimension by (k)
  5  measures (v, 0 shr)
  6  rules ( shr[any] = CASE WHEN sum(v)[any] = 0 THEN NULL ELSE sum(v)[any] END);


         K          V        SHR
---------- ---------- ----------
         1        100        200
         2        100        200

SQL> select *
  2  from (select level k, 100 v from dual connect by level<=2)
  3  model return updated rows
  4  dimension by (k)
  5  measures (v, 0 shr)
  6  rules ( shr[any] = nullif(sum(v)[any], 0));

         K          V        SHR
---------- ---------- ----------
         1        100        400
         2        100        400

SQL>
```

Therefor this is (at least a documentation :-) bug in 11r2

One gets the same results in *Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production*